# Log4j JMS appender example

Tags: java, log4j, jms

I tried to follow [this example](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html), but when I copied this class to my project I failed to run it.

I've no idea how my imports should look like, because eclipse suggests a lot of options. I tried

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
```

But I got:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This tutorial isn't clear for me. Do you know anything with more details (to absolute begginer)? Or maybe you know how to solve my problem with this exception?

EDIT:

log4.properties is exact copy of file in example

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, jms

## Be sure that ActiveMQ messages are not logged to 'jms' appender
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

## Configure 'jms' appender. You'll also need jndi.properties file in order to make it work
log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
```

Comment: can you show your log4j.properties file

Comment: @trebuchet the initialization of the log4j is failing. test by removing the jms appender from the root logger.configure the jms appender only for a single class and check the logging there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem in you configuration log4j.properties file. Look carefuly to it configuration. You can try to find tutorials about configuration log4j with google for example look [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm)

Comment: I added my `log4j.properties`, but it is an exact copy of file shown in example. Could it be wrong?

Comment: Btw I tried to google it. But it isn't that simple (e.g. tutorial from you doesn't mention JMSAppender at all)

Comment: I'll try to repeat this case now

Comment: If you still want to help, I created more detailed [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830415/how-to-use-jms-appender) about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the tested code -
In log4j.xml make entry for the JMSAppender class as below -

```
<appender name="amqAppender" class="com.appender.JMSQueueAppender"> 
         <param name="brokerUri" value="failover:(tcp://host1:port,tcp://host2:port,tcp://host3:port)?randomize=false" /> 
         <param name="queueName" value="MobiviteQueue" /> 
</appender>
```

And to use it -

```
<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="amqAppender" />
</root>
```

And the appeneder class is -

```
package com.appender;

import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;


public class JMSQueueAppender extends AppenderSkeleton implements Appender {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JMSQueueAppender.class);

private String brokerUri;
private String queueName;


@Override
protected synchronized void append(LoggingEvent event) {

    try {
        //System.out.println("JMSQueueAppender -----append  method is called  brokerUri ------ "+brokerUri);
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUri);

        // Create a Connection
        javax.jms.Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

        // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(event);

        // Tell the producer to send the message
        producer.send(message);
        // Clean up
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public String getBrokerUri() {
    return brokerUri;
}



public void setBrokerUri(String brokerUri) {
    this.brokerUri = brokerUri;
}



public String getQueueName() {
    return queueName;
}



public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
}



       public void close() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

        public boolean requiresLayout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```