# How to use JMS Appender?

Tags: java, log4j, jms

Inmy research about JMS Appenders I've found [turorial1](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html) and [tutorial2](http://code.google.com/p/log4j-jms-sample/wiki/ConfigurationGuide) . I've tried to follow them, but I couldn't run example program.

Fistly I created file log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, jms

#
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

#
log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
```

and jndi.properties

```
topic.logTopic=logTopic
```

Then I added Receiver.java to my project

```
public class Receiver implements MessageListener {

    public Receiver() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        Connection conn = factory.createConnection();
        Session sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        conn.start();
        MessageConsumer consumer = sess.createConsumer(sess.createTopic("logTopic"));
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Receiver.class);

        log.info("Test log");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        consumer.close();
        sess.close();
        conn.close();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Receiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            // receive log event in your consumer
            LoggingEvent event = (LoggingEvent)((ActiveMQObjectMessage)message).getObject();
            System.out.println("Received log [" + event.getLevel() + "]: "+ event.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need make Receiver to gather all logs from project, but I cannot even run this simple example. Probably I don't know how to configure it correctly, because I get this output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Did I miss adding some lines in code or some files to classpath? I'm new to log4j.

EDIT:
I set Logger in `AspectJ` class. But I think that also in `Receiver` Logger is created and log is sent, so probably it should be done in `Receiver`, not in other class in my project.

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportingAspect.class);

@Before("setLoggingFile()")
public void setProperties() {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}

ProjectJMS
|
\_ src
|   \_ packages...
\_jndi.propeties
\_log4j.properties
```

Comment: That WARN is just saying that you do not have log4j set up correctly. It is not the cause for the code to not work.

Comment: @CoolBeans As I've said, it is probably not configured, so you're right. My question is: how to configure it. Not in source code? Where/how? Could you help?

Comment: Please post the code where you initialize the logger, and also where do you put the properties file?

Comment: @ftom2 I edited my question. Both files are in main project folder.

Comment: When you say in main project folder, you mean under 'src'? also i meant the code where you do `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("someLogger")`.

Comment: @ftom2 Edit2 done. But as I've said, I'm not sure if problem can be in AspectJ class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure log4j use :
-Dlog4j.configuration= path to config file

Path to conf file CAN be:
À file in a path outside of classpath , if so préfix it with file:/// , example:

- -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/foobar.lcf

Else in classpath in That case:

- -Dlog4j.configuration=foobar.lcf where foobar.lcf is at root of your source folder

See:

- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

For jms:

-Add jms.jar at least to classpath

- ensure you have a JMS broker running ( activemq for example)

Regards

Philippe

Comment: I've added `activemq-all-5.60.jar` to classpath and I've run `activemq` in my console. Could you explain in more detais adding configuration? I added `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties` to arguments (in eclipse), but it didn't help. Probably I missunderstood what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the log4j.properties under 'src' folder so it'll be included in the classpath, since it's not there it is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated, that your Method `setProperties()` is called before you used your logger?

Usually that kind of error only pops up, when either the configuration file (log4j.properties) was not found while initializing log4j by `PropertyConfigurator`, or you tried to log something before you initialized log4j with your `PropertyConfigurator`.

First your should make sure, that `setProperties()` is called the way you expect it to be called and if this should work you could try to validate if the configuration can be loaded. From what I see, I guess your configuration file should be found. To validate this, you could load the configuration in several steps to make sure, it was found:

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.load( new FileInputStream( "log4j.properties" ) );
  PropertyConfigurator.configure( props );
```

If your configuration will not be found, you'll receive a `FileNotFoundException`.