# How to append errors from the server in a queue using log4j and then to consume them from a client existing in another project

Tags: java, logging, log4j, activemq-classic, appender

I tried to create a log4j filter that sends all error logs from my tomcat server in a JMS QUEUE and from there to do whatever I want with them.

1. First I test the functionality because is first time I am working with ActiveMQ, first time I am trying to make a log4j filter:

I added a JMSAppender to log4j2.xml as specified [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

```
<Appenders>
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="errorLogQueue"                                   
         factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
         factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"
         providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

and I created a class to test the functionality:

```
public class Log4JjmsAppenderWithActiveMQ implements MessageListener, Runnable{
    public static Logger logger2 = LogManager.getLogger(Log4JjmsAppenderWithActiveMQ.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Thread(new Log4JjmsAppenderWithActiveMQ())).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        try {
             connection = factory.createConnection();
             connection.start();
             session = connection.createSession(false, session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
             destination = session.createQueue("errorLogQueue");
             consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
             consumer.setMessageListener(this);
             logger2.error("error 1");
             logger2.error("error 2");
             logger2.info("info 1");
             logger2.debug("debug 1");

        } catch (JMSException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                consumer.close();
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
         Log4jLogEvent event = null;
        try { 
            event = (Log4jLogEvent)((ActiveMQObjectMessage)message).getObject();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LocalDate date =  Instant.ofEpochMilli(event.getTimeMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println("Received log [" + event.getLevel() + "]: "+ event.getMessage()+" at time: "+date);
    }
}
```

Running the app I get what I expected. Only errors are logged:

**Received log [ERROR]: error 1
Received log [ERROR]: error 2**

and also the ActiveMQ says that from 4 logged infos the two with level error were enqueued and dequeued error message.
[image]

Well, is first time I am working with ActiveMQ and also I don't know much about configuring servers.

2. So, my test worked but now I want to run this app when the tomcat starts and to send in the queue the errors that are on the server.

   - I think I have to change the providerURL value. If so, as host should I put my server host and for port should I use the port used for my server?

My @WebListener class implements ServletContextListener and in it's contextInitialized() method I configure the JMS server by calling the method bellow:

```
private void configActiveMQServer() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new   
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    try {
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = session.createQueue("errorLogQueue");
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

well, logging on the server the errors doesn't get into the queue.

*Maybe the jmsAppender is not the one I am looking for...*

3. So, I am trying to create a custom appender by extending AppenderSkeleton following examples lke: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876516/how-to-use-log4j2-jmsappender-with-activemq) and this [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) - search for "Appenders" in the documentation to see.
   For now, my custom appender looks like:

package com.h4p.server;

import java.io.Serializable;

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAliases;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;

@Plugin(name = Log4JErrorAppender.PLUGIN_NAME, category = "Core", elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
@PluginAliases(value="Log4JErrorAppender")
public class Log4JErrorAppender extends AppenderSkeleton{
     public static final String PLUGIN_NAME = "Log4JErrorAppender";
    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("xxx");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        if(event.getLevel() == Level.ERROR) {

        }

    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static Log4JErrorAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") String name,
            @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") boolean ignoreExceptions,
            @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
            @PluginElement("Filters") Filter filter) {
        if (name == null) {
            System.out.println("No name provided for Log4JErrorAppender");
            return null;
        }

        if (layout == null) {
            layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
        }
        return new Log4JErrorAppender();
    }
}
```

and in log4j2.xml I declared:

```
<Log4JErrorAppender name="errorQueue"/>
```

but I have this error:

```
localhost-startStop-1 ERROR appenders Appenders has no parameter that matches element Log4JErrorAppender
```

- Could you please give me a good guide to create a custom appender in order to satisfy my need?

  - **The main question is how to get the errors from my server and send (append) them to a queue from where I can consume the error messages from a client in another project? What log4j appender should I use? Give me some examples.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did is fine. To break it down, these are the components of your "system":

1. *Log producer* - Tomcat that runs an application that produces logs and publishes them to ActiveMQ. Note here, JMSAppender is exactly what you need. You can see an example in the official ActiveMQ documentation: [How to use JMS Appender](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html)
2. *ActiveMQ instance* - you need to set up a standalone ActiveMQ server.

   > I think I have to change the providerURL value. If so, as host should I put my server host and for port should I use the port used for my server?

   You need to provide the host and port as parameters to the JMS Appender (exactly as you did in the log4j xml config).
3. *Log consumer* - this can the same application as in (1) or a different one. The correct way to consume messages is by implementing a `MessageListener` and handling incoming messages in `onMessage(..)`

   As it seems, it's not clear for you how to bootstrap the last component (3). What you need to do is to initialize your message listener inside `contextInitialized(...)`. When you do that, you will have to bind it to a specific topic/queue. This needs to be the same as the one you publish logs to in (1). You can see a brief example below:

---

```
public class LogMessageListenerExample implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
    {
        ConnectionFactory conn = createConnectionFactory();

        Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        conn.start();

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(sess.createTopic("topic/queue-name-to-listen"));
        LogMessageListener listener = new LogMessageListener();
        consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
    }

    private ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory()
    {
        // create connection factory with host and port for your ActiveMQ instance
    }
}

public class LogMessageListener implements MessageListener
{
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        // handle message
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the providerURL value: "tcp://localhost:90"  (my local server runs on port 90) and I get the error explained here: [link](http://activemq.apache.org/javaxjmsjmsexception-wire-format-negociation-timeout-peer-did-not-send-his-wire-format.html).  I think the port on witch activemq runs is 61616 and that's why I get this error

Comment: If by "local server" you are referring to Tomcat, you should be passing as arguments to the connection factory the port and host for ActiveMQ, not for Tomcat. And yes, the default connector port for ActiveMQ is 61616. You can change that from activemq.xml, if it is ever neded.